# Sybase ASE DB - Identify the operation performed on a particular table - Insert/Update/delete/Truncate

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase, dml

Hope you are doing good!

I would like to know, if there's any way where we can identify the operations performed on a Sybase ASE DB. Say for ex: I have 1000 tables on which multiple operations are being performed, such as Update/Delete/Insert/Truncate operations.

Is there a way where we can query any audit tables/metadata tables by providing the desired table name?

Any help would be really appreciated.

PS: I know in Teradata we have this feature using pdcrinfo.dbqllogtbl_hst. Is there any similar thing available in Sybase DB?

Thanks in advance,
JP

Comment: Something similar -   

select  A.LOGDATE, A.PROCID, A.QUERYID, OBJECTDATABASENAME, OBJECTTABLENAME 
FROM PDCRDATA.DBQLOGTBL_HST A , PDCRDATA.DBQLOBJTBL_HST B 
WHERE A.LOGDATE = B.LOGDATE 
AND A.PROCID = B.PROCID
AND A.QUERYID = B.QUERYID 
AND STATEMENTTYPE IN ( 'INSERT','SELECT') )
AND OBJECTTYPE = 'TAB'

Comment: Sybase ASE: **a)** auditing, DBA needs to setup/configure a db to capture audit data, for high volumes of auditing expect to see some performance degradation, DBA will likely need to setup a separate db for offloading 'old' auditing data (eg, if the main audit db holds 12 hrs of auditing data then an archive process will need to copy data to a larger db for historical data; **b)** MDA tables, also requires DBA setup and configuration, also requires a separate db for maintaining archived/historical data, used more for P&T analysis but could be used for some level of auditing

Comment: Thanks Mark! DBAs had SQL tracing enabled long back and we might be opting the same option this time. We have the liability of Performance degradation on the prod DB, but we will be monitoring it actively.